# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll. String from Access

Tags: c#, reader, oledbdatareader

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

```
OleDbCommand commandmenu = new OleDbCommand();
        commandmenu.Connection = oleConn;
        string querymenu = "select * from AllMeals where MOTD = '1'";
        commandmenu.CommandText = querymenu;
        string menutype = "";
        string menuitemname = "";
        OleDbDataReader readermenu = commandmenu.ExecuteReader();
        while (readermenu.Read())
        {
            menutype = readermenu.GetString(3);
            menuitemname = readermenu.GetString(1);
        }
```

I'm trying to get strings from my access database, but I am getting this error, is there something wrong with my query text? MOTD is a yes/no field in the AllMeals table.

Answer (score 0):

there is issue with your query. try this:

```
    string querymenu = "select * from AllMeals where MOTD ="+ true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `single quotes`

```
string querymenu = "select * from AllMeals where MOTD = 1";
```